# Proving that a set of functions is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

We've given that $V$ is a vector space and that $L(V)$ the set with functions $T:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $T(a_1f_1+a_2f_2)=a_1T(f_1)+a_2T(f_2)$. We must show that $L(V)$ is a vector space.

I was looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49733/prove-in-full-detail-that-the-set-is-a-vector-space) question asked before, and the top answer talks about the set inheriting properties from $\mathbb{R^2}$. I was wonering if this were also the case in this problem, or whether we must show all eight properties of a vector space hold for this set. In the second case, I'm having trouble showing four properties. Namely:

1. There always exists an $f,g\in L(V)$ s.t. $f+g=0$
2. $c(kf)=(ck)f$
3. $1f = f$
4. $(c+k)f=cf+kf$

I think I have an idea for the last one. Suppose $f\in L(V)$. Then we have:

$$(c+k)(f)(v) = (c+k)(f(v)) = cf(v)+kf(v)$$

Comment: Hint: check those properties pointwise. For example, your third property is equivalent to checking that $1f(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in V$, which is clearly true.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I'm sorry, what do you mean by "pointwise?" For 2. can I say: $c(kf)(v) = c(kf(v)) = (ck)f(v)$? It seems just like an exercise in manipulating algebraic equations.

Comment: Pointwise means that you fix an element $x\in V$ and then check the desired property holds for $f(x)$ instead of $f$. If it does, then you're good to go. Your (2) is good. And, indeed, the whole exercise is just a manipulation of algebraic expressions.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Awesome. Thank you. The only one I'm really struggling with is 1. I know that $f\in L(V)$, but I don't know how to show that $-f$ is also in $L(V)$.

Comment: So, you define $g(x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$. Now you have to check that this $g$ is linear. So you write $g(ax+by) = -f(ax+by) = -(af(x)+bf(y)) = a(-f(x))+b(-f(y)) =\ldots$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy we would have $-af(x)-bf(y)$, which shows that $g$ is linear?

Comment: Indeed we would.